# read .txt file into dictionary python

Tags: python

In file is this:

```
count=50
value=100k
unit=Ohm
package=0603
description=Chip Resistor
supplier=Digikey
supplierpartnumber=311-100KHRCT-ND
price=0.009
currency=CHF
```

And the output should be like this:

```
{"RC0805FR -07100 KL": { 
"count": "100", 
"description": "Chip Resistor", 
"value": "100k", 
"unit": "Ohm", ...}
```

I do not have an idea how to transform the file in the correct format

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: Your output does not relate to the input (see count). Please check them. And do you really want to cast the count into a string?

Comment: i open the file and tried to split it with a for loop... don't work

Comment: yes i want to cast it...and the input and output is correctly. it must be so

Comment: Do you have a *specific* question? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: The information you've provided is incomplete.  Where does "RC0805FR -07100 KL" come from?

Comment: My question is how i should code it(from file to dictionary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi this should help,

```
myDict = {}
with open('yourFile.txt', 'r') as myFile: # make sure yourFile.txt is in the same directory as this code, or specify the full path to the text file
    myFile = myFile.readlines()
for item in myFile:
    refined = (item.strip('\n').split('='))
    myDict[refined[0]] = refined[1]
print(myDict)
```

Comment: list index out of range...but i should get it

Comment: Oh, what could cause that is if some lines in your txt file isn't in the format "aKey"="aValue" as the example txt file suggest.

Answer (score 4):

```py
with open('myfile.txt') as f:
    s = f.read().strip()
    d = dict([ x.split('=') for x in s.split('\n') ])
    print(d)
```